# Service charge per unit for basic computer repair/maintenance

Tags: pay-rate, price, software

I have a question regarding how much I should charge per computer repaired or maintained. Basically, I applied for a job doing basic work on PCs and the employer wants to know what I'd charge as a service fee per unit. I have never had to come up with numbers for that before, as I am payed hourly at my job now. So what would be a modest price per unit for fixes such as hdd formatting, installation of windows 8 (*sigh*), some software installs, and basic hardware diagnostics?

Thanks!

EDIT: If it means anything, there are 13 PCs that need to be done as far as I know.

Comment: Is this for a particular gig, or for a job?

Comment: This is unanswerable. Fees would easily vary by country, region, state, city, experience, etc. What one person charges is almost *never* the same as what another person would charge.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're doing this as a freelancer rather than being employed? Are you thinking of starting up your own PC Support business where you react to client calls?

If so, you need to get a clear idea of your costs - including the 'dead time' of travel to & from site.

I wouldn't try & do too much that's menu based, it only confuses users - they just want their machine to start working again!

Decide your hourly rate & then your experience will tell you how long the job will take. Some will go over, some will be done ahead of time but you'll average out.

Try Googling the hourly rate of similar local PC repair businesses.

FWIW, I used to charge £45/hr about 5 years back for onsite & £35 for anything thatcame into the workshop. The only fixed price I did was for virus'd machines at £75 including a general Wndows cleanup.

If your client wants a monthly service contract then that's another thing entirely - budget around £20-£35/seat for PCs but only once you've got them to a good standard and of course servers are orders of magnitude more expensive.

HTH

Comment: @zfollette: do keep in mind that your hourly rate must be higher than your rate as an employee, as you have to afford taxes and general costs.